# MongoDB Java driver much slower than console with $gte/$lte

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, mongodb-java

I'm using MongoDB 4.0.1 with Java driver (MongoDB-driver-sync) 3.8.0

My collection has 564'039 elements with 13 key-values, 2 of which are maps with 10 more key-values.

If I execute the following query in the console, it gives me the results in less than a second:

```
db.getCollection('tracking_points').find({c: 8, d: 11,
  t: {$gte: new Date("2018-08-10"), $lte: new Date("2018-09-10")}
})
```

But if I execute this in Java it takes more than 30 seconds:

```
collection.find(
    and(
        eq("c", clientId),
        eq("d", unitId),
        gte("t", start),
        lte("t", end)
        )
    ).forEach((Block<Document>) document -> {
        // nothing here
    });
```

There is an index on "t" (timestamp) and without it, the console find takes few seconds.

How can this be fixed?

Edit: Here is the log from the DB after the java query:

```
"2018-09-21T08:06:38.842+0300 I COMMAND  [conn9236] command fleetman_dev.tracking_points command: count { count: \"tracking_points\", query: {}, $db: \"fleetman_dev\", $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } } planSummary: COUNT keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 numYields:0 reslen:45 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_msg 0ms", 
"2018-09-21T08:06:38.862+0300 I COMMAND  [conn9236] command fleetman_dev.tracking_points command: find { find: \"tracking_points\", filter: { c: 8, d: 11, t: { $gte: new Date(1536526800000), $lte: new Date(1536613200000) } }, $db: \"fleetman_dev\", $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { t: 1 } cursorid:38396803834 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:0 nreturned:101 reslen:24954 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { ", 
"2018-09-21T08:06:39.049+0300 I COMMAND  [conn9236] command fleetman_dev.tracking_points command: getMore { getMore: 38396803834, collection: \"tracking_points\", $db: \"fleetman_dev\", $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } } originatingCommand: { find: \"tracking_points\", filter: { c: 8, d: 11, t: { $gte: new Date(1536526800000), $lte: new Date(1536613200000) } }, $db: \"fleetman_dev\", $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { t: 1 } cursorid:38396803834 keysExamined:33810 doc",
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the execution time on the MongoDB side using `db.setLogLevel(1)`? I would guess you are comparing apples and pears here because the Java driver will do e.g. deserialization which is generally pretty costly.

Comment: Maybe I can't read the log correctly, but it didn't gave me any clues, or times. I'm attaching it to the main post.

Comment: Like in the first row at the end there should generally be milliseconds that tell you how long an operation took. I would bet you'll see identical numbers there when running it through Java or anything else. That would prove that the slowness you're experiencing comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Is there a better way to retrieve the data in Java? The block I pasted is the whole code that is slow.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do inside the loop you can e.g. use projection to limit the numbers of fields returned and hence reduce the deserialization effort.

Comment: Using projection the time dropped significantly, but I hope there're more tricks to optimize the processing time.
I have to iterate over all results, they're history of movement of a vehicle) and they're about 600'000-700'000.
In another systems (online), the same data (same vehicles send data to the mine and the other system) is processed much faster...

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Java driver correctly but your conclusion - that the Java driver is much slower than the console - is based on an invalid comparison. The two code blocks is your question are not equivalent. In the shell variant you retrieve a cursor. In the Java variant you retrieve a cursor **and** you walk over the contents of that cursor.

A valid comparison between the Mongo shell and the Java driver would either have to include walking over the cursor in the shell variant, for example:

```
db.getCollection('tracking_points').find({c: 8, d: 11,
  t: {$gte: new Date("2018-08-10"), $lte: new Date("2018-09-10")}
}).forEach(
  function(myDoc) { 
    // nothing here 
  } 
)
```

Or it would have to remove walking over the cursor from the Java variant, for example:

```
collection.find(
    and(
        eq("c", clientId),
        eq("d", unitId),
        gte("t", start),
        lte("t", end)
        )
    );
```

Both of these would be more valid forms of comparison. If you run either of those you'll see that the elapsed times are **much** closer to each other. The follow on question might be 'why does it take 30s to read this data?'. If so, the fact that you can get the cursor back sub second tells us that the issue is not about *indexing*, instead it is likely to be related to the *amount of data* being read by the query.

To isolate where the issue is occurring you could gather elasped times for the following:

1. read the data, iterating over each document but do not parse each document
2. read the data and parse each document while reading

If the elapsed time for no. 2 is not much more than the elapsed time for no. 1 then you know that the issue is not in parsing and is more likely to be in network transfer. If the elapsed time for no. 2 is much greater than no. 1 then you know that the issue is in parsing and you can dig into the parse call to attribute the elapsed time. It could be constrained resources on the client (CPU and/or memory) or a sub optimal parse implementation. I can't tell at this remove but using the above approach to isolate where the problem resides will at least help you to direct your investigation.

Comment: Is there another way to parse the data? I used the suggestion of projections and this greatly decreased the processing time, but it's still slow.
The results count is between 600 and 700'000 documents and the fields are reduced to 5 using projection.
Any tips or tricks will be great, thanks!

Comment: I have added some suggestions to the answer

Comment: So, `collection.find(...);` gets the cursor but doesn't read the data and `collection.find(...).forEach((Block<Document>) document -> { // nothing here });` gets the cursor and does read the data but does not parse each document.

Comment: Are you sure if the forEach block is empty, the data is not parsed? I think the document is the ready, parsed BSON data?
As for the times, after the projection, 1. runs for about 9.5-10s seconds and 2. for 10.7s

Comment: I think that depends on what you mean by "parsed". I had assumed you meant something like 'transform the Document into my own type' but perhaps you meant ' serialise the data for transfer to the client and then deserialise it into a document on the client side'.